# listview with custom adapter is not showing thumbnail...instead its showing diffrent picture

Tags: android, listview, video

```
  CustomVideoListViewAdapter VideolistAdapter = new CustomVideoListViewAdapter(this,R.layout.video_list, songs);
                audiolistview.setAdapter(VideolistAdapter);
                audiolistview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                        music_column_index = musicCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA);
                        cursorPoristion = i;
                        musicCursor.moveToPosition(i);
                        String filename = musicCursor.getString(music_column_index);
                        mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
                        mediaController.setMediaPlayer(videoView);
                        mediaController.setEnabled(true);
                        videoView.setVideoPath(filename);
                        videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
                        videoView.start();
                        videoView.setZOrderOnTop(true);
                    }
                });


  //custom adapter is here
public class CustomVideoListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<AudioModel> {
Context vcontext;
public CustomVideoListViewAdapter(Context context, int resourceId,
                             List<AudioModel> items) {
    super(context, resourceId, items);
    this.vcontext= context;
}
private class VideoViewHolder {
    ImageView imageView;
    TextView txtTitle;
    TextView txtDesc;
}
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    CustomVideoListViewAdapter.VideoViewHolder holder = null;
    AudioModel rowItem = getItem(position);
    String path=rowItem.getaPath();
    Bitmap thumb = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(path,
            MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);

    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) vcontext
            .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.video_list, null);
        holder = new CustomVideoListViewAdapter.VideoViewHolder();
        holder.txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.video_file_nameView);
        holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.videothumbnail_view);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else
        holder = (CustomVideoListViewAdapter.VideoViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    holder.txtTitle.setText(rowItem.getaName());
    holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(thumb);

    return convertView;
}
```

}

1. when running this application code I am not getting the thumbnail of the video files list and video is not showing but sound is playing.
2. I have set two different custom adapter to show video list and audio list...the problem I am getting here is video list is not showing as expected from the video list layout...

Comment: plz somebody help

Comment: implement with BaseAdapter

Comment: if i will use base adapter then i will not be able to use audiomodel

Comment: brother i tried with baseadapter still same problem